# Preprocessing required for grayscale X-ray images when performing transfer learning with inception-resnet-v2?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am attempting to fine-tune the inception-resnet-v2 model with grayscale x-ray images of breast cancers (mammograms) using TensorFlow. As the images consists of both the left and right breasts, I have opted to do the following preprocessing:

1. The standard image whitening by subtracting the pixels mean value and dividing by the pixels variance.
2. Randomly flipping the images left and right in case there are more left or right breast images.

However, I am unsure whether the following options would be useful as well, which I hope you could verify whether my reasoning is correct:

1. Distorted bounding box crop. I have actually resized my images all
   into the height and width size of 299 needed for the
   inception-resnet-v2 model, but doing this will give me a smaller
   crop. I could potentially resize my original images again to
   1024x1024, and then perform distorted bounding box crop. My question
   is would this actually be useful?

   One thing is my images actually
   have around 30% of the pixels with nearly 255 in value (the
   background is almost entirely black), and only around 70% useful
   content. I am worried if randomly cropping could result in only the
   black background crops for certain images, and this would train the
   models on the content that are not really useful.
2. However, could the black background be useful in deducing the size of the useful content (i.e. each image's proportion of black background is unique, so could this be a potential information)? I am unsure if this will be a significant factor though.
3. Color distortion. Randomly adjusting the brightness, saturation, contrast and hue of the images (4 kinds of distortion  done together). However, as my image is grayscale, would these distortions be significant? I'm suspecting these color distortions might be universal regardless of the number of color channels (since grayscale is just 2 channels short of a standard RGB, and the adjustments are probably done per channel).

Are there any more data preprocessing I could try?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: I have a similar situation with prostate data. Do you have a good proposition for "1. Distorted bounding box crop"? :)